# How to get only column names as the following sample?

Tags: sql

currently, I have a string of column names as below (this string is computed in stored pro, and column name is got from several tables):

```
@str = 'select FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3'
```

in stored, how can I do to return a datatable with no data and @str is list of column name?
I tried to query like that:

```
exec (@str)
```

but it requires table for it. But I don't want to put table into because it will query to get data, and it will take a long time to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Put 'null' in front of each column name, as in:

```
select null as FieldName1, null as FieldName2, null as FieldName3
```

Comment: Depending on what you're using it for you may also want to cast the fields (i.e. "cast(null as int) as FieldName1").  Don't know what you're using this for but if the consuming code needs to see the data types then I 'think' that may also help.

Comment: yeah, you definately help me so much. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apply where condition which have no matching data like

**EDIT**:

Thanks to **@Brandon Moore**:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM   myTable
WHERE  1= 0
```

Comment: @ThangLang Actually, my answer will get you what I think you're really after, but it 'does' return 1 row of null values.  To get exactly what you were asking for (i.e. no results) then you would need to incorporate Yaqub's answer into your code as well.  But the where clause could be as simple as "where 1 = 0".

Comment: where 1 = 0 GREAT solution @Brandon Moore!!